# Make config file as a part of static library through CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I need to make by config file as a part of my static library which means if some project links to my static library the config file should be copied to build directory automatically for that project. This behavior should be the same for all projects referencing the static library.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
libabc
   abc.cfg
project1
   build
      abc.cfg  -- Because project1 references static library libabc
```

I don't want to change the `CMakeLists.txt` for every project.

Comment: if statement and then add a copy of the config ?

Comment: add a copy if library is linked . no conditions

Answer (score 0):

To know if a library is link you can get the list of all linked libraries to a target with [`get_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/get_property.html?highlight=get_property) and search for [`LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake-properties.7.html?highlight=link_libraries#properties-on-targets) property.

With `get_property()` you will have the list of linked librairies. You can search is yours are in with [`string()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/string.html?highlight=string#search-and-replace).

Then when you find your libraries which are linked  you can use [`file()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/file.html?highlight=copy#copy) to copy your config file in corresponding folder.

You get a code like that

```
get_property(MY_LINKED_LIBRARIES TARGET ${MY_TARGET} PROPERTY LINK LIBRARIES)
string(FIND ${MY_LINKED_LIBRARIES} ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} LIBRARY_FIND)
if (LIBRARY_FIND NOT EQUAL -1)
    file (COPY "abc.cfg" DESTINATION "${MY_LIBRARY_NAME}/abc.cfg")
endif ()
```

With a `for` loop for all your libraries.

Comment: how do i know the target before hand? some random project can link to the library

Comment: The target is your project. You can do a function to call it on every project